# PyTorch to CoreML, input issue

Tags: python, ios, pytorch, coreml

I am trying to run my PyTorch network on an iOS device.
However, I face the issue of an incorrect input format when I put my network in Apple's demo (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/classifying_images_with_vision_and_core_ml), my input is a MultiArray (Double 3 x 224 x 224) and the one used in the demo is Image (Color 224 x 224).

I didn't find a way to get an input Image with all the research I have done. 
To convert my network to .mlmodel, I save it as a .onnx with torch.onnx._export and then I use this library https://github.com/onnx/onnx-coreml to get the .mlmodel.

Do anyone of you have experienced the same issue and have a possible solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you need to put the name of your input into `image_input_names` and then it will turn the input from a MultiArray into an Image.

Comment: I already tried to do so but it didn’t changed it

Comment: any luck on this? I am facing the same issue